How can I repair a permanent push connect hose bibb that's leaking?
The previous hose bibb in my backyard was leaking so I decided to replace entirely. I sweated it off and thought I cleaned the copper pipe properly before installing a new push to connect bibb. I got the new bibb on easy enough but must not have done a good enough job removing the old solder on the under side as it sprays a mist of water out the back.
I didn't realize it was a permanent connection (thought it would have a release collar) and there is only about an inch left of copper pipe between the bibb and wall. Not sure what's the best way to fix. The three options I'm thinking are:

Cut as close to the leaking bibb and hope there is enough room to attach a new bibb (needs 15/16 of an inch)

Try and seal behind the leaking bibb. Could I seal with solder? I worry that would damage a gasket or something in the bibb. Or possibly seal with some sort of rubber clamp?

Try to remove the bibb. I know it is "permanent" and I wasn't able to find anything online about how to get it off, but is it possible?


This is the bibb
What would you do? Any help or suggestions is appreciated!



The manufacturer and model number of the bibb may help you get good answers.

None of these things are truly permanent. A removal tool will probably let it slip right off. See YouTube and the soda can trick.

Is this your huckleberry? I'd try unscrewing it at the two hex castings. Are you sure you have it pushed on all the way? It can take some force to get the seal over the pipe. Try that first.

This is the bibb
I have an aqua dynamics push-fit removal tool but it doesn't work on this. At the bottom of the tag on the bibb it says "permanent installation" so I doubt it's meant to work with a removal tool.
